# Why would Google give rich snippets to a non canonical URL but the canonical never displays them?

Tags: canonical-url, rich-snippets, query-string

Various parameters slightly adapt my page's content such as `?showreviewsall` or `?filterresults`. All pages with parameters point to the canonical through a `canonical` tag.

Since the beginning, Google sometimes shows rich snippets to pages with parameters but not the canonical. Why would this be?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't using canonical tags correctly.   Canonical tags are supposed to point to identical pages with alternate URLs.   The parameters you use seem to indicate you are changing the content on the pages.   Google is probably ignoring your canonical tags.   If you look in the new Search Console Beta you will probably see "Google chose different canonical than user" for a lot of URLs.

Comment: Thanks, checking this out now. 

Canonical tags are supposed to point to identical pages with alternate URLs. - This point I agree and disagree with. I think the terminology Google uses is "near identical pages". 

But in any case, why would they show rich snippets for non-canonical but never for canonical?

Comment: I think Google wants rich data to be unique.  So if it is ignoring your canonicals you may have duplicate issues.